# PHP Warning: Division by zero

Tags: php, divide-by-zero

I'm learning php and built an experimental form-based calculator (also using html & POST method) that returns values to a table. The calculator is functional when I enter my values and click submit, but I keep getting two "Division by zero" errors on the last line when I first run the code. I can't seem seem to find a logical solution or explanations when searching here or via Google. Any explanation you can provide to a newb will be appreciated.

```
<?php 

error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

//calculate the difference in price

$itemQty = $_POST['num1'];

$itemCost = $_POST['num2'];

$itemSale = $_POST['num3'];

$shipMat = $_POST['num4'];

$diffPrice = $itemSale - $itemCost;

$actual = ($diffPrice - $shipMat) * $itemQty;

$diffPricePercent = (($actual * 100) / $itemCost) / $itemQty ;

?>
```

Comment: could you post the relevant code?

Comment: Why are you doing `+ null`? And do all variables have a value?

Comment: Null was my attempt which I meant to remove before posting

Comment: @Chip - can you also add in a `var_dump($_POST)` so we can see what the incoming variables are?

Comment: If any of the variables doesn't have a value you most likely get that error.

Comment: "errors on the last line when I first run the code".  This code won't work unless something is posted to it.  You need to check `if(isset($_POST['num1']))`.

Comment: What is `$itemCost` if you do `echo var_dump( $itemCost );`?

Comment: @Sumurai8: `var_dump` doesn't return anything, it echos for you.  You don't need the `echo` there.

Comment: Well, don't divide by zero, then.

Comment: The variables call the input fields on the form which are blank when I first load the form. It's a calculator designed for end users to plug in their own values. Am I making sense?

Comment: @Chip You do make sense, but, as I wrote in my answer, you shouldn't do any calculations with the data you don't have (yet).

Comment: @RocketHazmat I never knew that. With or without echo it produces the same output, but the echo is indeed not needed.

Comment: That makes sense to me now. Thank you!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to wrap your form processing code in a conditional so it doesn't run when you first open the page. Something like so:

```
if($_POST['num1'] > 0 && $_POST['num2'] > 0 && $_POST['num3'] > 0 && $_POST['num4'] > 0){

  $itemQty = $_POST['num1'];
  $itemCost = $_POST['num2'];
  $itemSale = $_POST['num3'];
  $shipMat = $_POST['num4'];

  $diffPrice = $itemSale - $itemCost;
  $actual = ($diffPrice - $shipMat) * $itemQty;
  $diffPricePercent = (($actual * 100) / $itemCost) / $itemQty ;
}
```

Comment: Also, this will only process if all values are greater than zero.

Answer (score 7):

```
$diffPricePercent = (($actual * 100) / $itemCost) / $itemQty;
```

`$itemCost` and `$itemQty` are returning `null` or zero, check them what they come with to code from user input

also to check if it's not empty data add:

```
if (!empty($_POST['num1'])) {
    $itemQty = $_POST['num1'];
}
```

and you can check this link for POST validation before using it in variable

https://www.virendrachandak.com/techtalk/php-isset-vs-empty-vs-is_null/

Comment: That doesn't work for (string)"0.00". Try if (isset($_POST['num1']) && (float)$_POST['num1'] != 0)

Answer (score 5):

Try using

```
$var = @($val1 / $val2);
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".

Comment: If I try `$var = $val1 / $val2;` or `$var = @($val1 / $val2);` I get the same error...

Comment: Adding the @ symbol works for my case, not sure why though, thanks

Answer (score 4):

If the expected value can be 0 (therefore does not need validation), I do this to keep things in one line:

```
$percentage = $sum1 / ($sum2 ?: 1)
```

Answer (score 3):

If a variable is not set then it is `NULL` and if you try to divide something by null you will get a divides by zero error

Answer (score 2):

If it shows an error on the first run only, it's probably because you haven't sent any POST data. You should check for POST variables before working with them. Undefined, null, empty array, empty string, etc. are all considered false; and when PHP auto-casts that false boolean value to an integer or a float, it becomes zero. That's what happens with your variables, they are not set on the first run, and thus are treated as zeroes.

```
10 / $unsetVariable
```

becomes

```
10 / 0
```

Bottom line: check if your inputs exist and if they are valid before doing anything with them, also enable error reporting when you're doing local work as it will save you a lot of time. You can enable all errors to be reported like this: `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

To fix your specific problem: don't do any calculations if there's no input from your form; just show the form instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this. You have this error because we can not divide by `'zero' (0)` value. So we want to validate before when we do calculations.

```
if ($itemCost != 0 && $itemCost != NULL && $itemQty != 0 && $itemQty != NULL) 
{
    $diffPricePercent = (($actual * 100) / $itemCost) / $itemQty;
}
```

And also we can validate `POST` data. Refer following

```
$itemQty = isset($_POST['num1']) ? $_POST['num1'] : 0;

$itemCost = isset($_POST['num2']) ? $_POST['num2'] : 0;

$itemSale = isset($_POST['num3']) ? $_POST['num3'] : 0;

$shipMat = isset($_POST['num4']) ? $_POST['num4'] : 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

when my divisor has 0 value

```
if ($divisor == 0) {
    $divisor = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if(isset($itemCost) != '' && isset($itemQty) != '')
{
    $diffPricePercent = (($actual * 100) / $itemCost) / $itemQty;
}
else
{
    echo "either of itemCost or itemQty are null";
}
```

Comment: Same as Ahmed's answer. It doesn't work for (string)"0.00".

Answer (score 0):

A lot of the answers here do not work for (string)"0.00".

Try this:

```
if (isset($_POST['num1']) && (float)$_POST['num1'] != 0) {
  ...
}
```

Or even more strict:

```
if (isset($_POST['num1']) && is_numeric($_POST['num1']) && (float)$_POST['num1'] != 0) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the variable using * 100 $actual has a value or it will return an error.

```
if ( ! empty( $actual ) ) :

$diffPricePercent = (($actual * 100) / $itemCost) / $itemQty ;

endif;
```